# Concurrent processing with the requirement of sequentially run awaited sub-tasks (in a console app)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to find the best way of handling concurrent processing of items that is composed of individual sub-tasks that need to be executed sequentially (C# / .net 4.6)

i.e. Process objects in a list concurrently, but execute the series of (async awaited) sub tasks within sequentially -- *and only run code that comes after once all operations are complete.*

pseudo-code:

```
public async Task SynchronizeItems() 
{
   List<Items> items = await client.RetrieveItems();
   foreach (var item in collection) // but in parallel
   {
      await item.DoThingA()
      await item.DoThingB()
      await item.DoThingC()
   }   
   // **only run code here when all sub tasks for all items are complete**
}
```

Greater context (in simplified form): I have an executable that needs to run as a scheduled task every N minutes. The entry point/Main method of Program initializes an ItemSyncService and calls SynchronizeItems(). Because SynchronizeItems() is async, the entire process immediately exits when the first await is encountered, as control is returned to the Main method.

(Simply adding calling SynchronizeItems().Wait() doesn't work, as this is a simplified scenario. In reality, the call hierarchy is really complex, with assemblies being dynamically loaded and methods called, etc, etc.)

To prevent this (based on a post I saw on Stack Overflow), I've added a ManualResetEvent so I can manually control when "all tasks are complete".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ManualResetEvent completionEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
   _executor = new ItemService();
   _executor.SynchronizeItems(completionEvent)

   // wait for completion events to be set before exiting the method
   completionEvent.WaitOne()
}
```

The synchronize method then looks like the following :

```
public async Task SynchronizeItems(ManualResetEvent completionEvent) 
{
   List<Items> items = await client.RetrieveItems();
   foreach (var item in collection) // but in parallel
   {
      await item.DoThingA()
      await item.DoThingB()
      await item.DoThingC()
   }   
   // ** only run code here when all sub tasks for all items are complete**
   // signal completion
   completionEvent.Set()
}
```

Changing this to use Parallel ForEach for Item-level concurrency looks like this:

```
public async Task SynchronizeItems(ManualResetEvent completionEvent) 
{
   List<Items> items = await client.RetrieveItems();
   Parallel.ForEach(items, async (item) => // in parallel now
   {
      await item.DoThingA()
      await item.DoThingB()
      await item.DoThingC()
   }   
   **// only run code here when all sub tasks for all items are complete **
   // signal completion
   completionEvent.Set() // ** this now runs immediately without waiting **
}
```

However, when this is done, the completionEvent will be called immediately after starting the tasks for each item.

I found a 3rd party library that implements a ParallelForEachAsync (https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable). It appears this will prevent the completionEvent from being set until after all awaited tasks for all Items have complete.

but I'm wondering if I'm going about this incorrectly? 
Originally when I wrote this, I was testing as a console app and had a ReadKey() in interactive mode, so I didn't run into the async-related process exiting problem.

Comment: One of the big issue with Console applications, is keeping the console alive until the tasks return. In a GUI, you got the Event Loop doing that part for you. The `Task.Wait` functions are there to actually block, until a specific (group of) Tasks finishes.

Comment: Are the `DoThingA/B/C` methods making I/O requests, or CPU-intensive tasks?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is used for parallelism, not concurrency. That's why a `ParallelForEachAsync` is meaningless. What you want can probably be solved by using an ActionBlock or TransformBlock with a MaxDegreeOfParallelism >1. The blocks in the DataFlow library preserve the order of items even when DOP>1

Comment: The DoThing methods make various async HTTP requests (basically grabbing data from somewhere and sending it somewhere else)

Comment: @looselycoupled Ok, then my answer is applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `DoThings` methods are making I/O requests and not CPU-bound operations, then you can move the item processing to its own method:

```
private async Task ProcessItem(Items item) {
    await item.DoThingA();
    await item.DoThingB();
    await item.DoThingC();
}
```

Then build a list of `Task` objects for each one, then wait for them all to be finished:

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    taskList.Add(ProcessItem(item));
}
await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
// you will get here only when all the items are processed
```

When `await` acts on an incomplete `Task`, it returns its own incomplete `Task` and execution returns to the calling method. So if `DoThingA()` makes a network request, for example, then as soon as that network request is sent, execution returns back to the `SynchronizeItems` method and the next one in the list is started.

So doing this will start everything all at once, then as the replies come back, things finish up. That "finishing up" may or may not happen on separate threads. It depends on the type of application.

- In an application that has no synchronization context (ASP.NET Core, or console app, or Windows Service) then each one will finish on background threads.
- If this application does have a synchronization context (ASP.NET or desktop app) then each one will wait until the main thread is idle before finishing up. If you know you don't need the context (e.g. in ASP.NET, you aren't using the `HttpContext` in any of this, or in a UI app, you're not changing the UI), then you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to tell it that you don't need to return to the same context it started from and it will finish faster:

```
private async Task ProcessItem(Items item) {
    await item.DoThingA().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await item.DoThingB().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await item.DoThingC().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Microsoft has a very well-written series of articles on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). Look at the table of contents on the left for the rest of the articles in that section.

Comment: .NET already solves this problem with the DataFlow library and lately, with Channels. A DataFlow block like ActionBlock or TransformBlock maintain the order of the processed items, even when they use more than one task to process them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Interesting... I'll have to read up on that. But it seems that's only available in .NET Core?

Comment: No, Dataflow is 8 years old - it came with .NET 4.5 back in 2012. Channels are also available everywhere as a .NET Standard 2.0 package

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hrm. When I look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow), and change the version to any .NET Framework version, it says it's not available for that version. Am I looking at the right thing?

Comment: The site has a bug. DataFlow came out in .NET 4.5 as a NuGet package. I've been using it that long. If you simply search for it in NuGet, you'll see it's available

Comment: Placing the sequentially executed sub tasks in a method and than awaiting the returned task of the method itself (in aggregate with WhenAll) seems really obvious in hindsight. Although I'll still need to figure out concurrency control/throttling. I could segment the collection of the Items into sub-collections and await the response as a poor man's concurrent level.  
Related question. Is there any benefit to using Parallel ForEach (either native or the extension method version mentioned in the post) with code written for the async task-based paradigm?